# jQuery Disable Method - why so transparent?

Tags: jquery, slider

i have a jQuery slider that i have disabled, and it is almost completly transparent...

is there a way to keep it disable, but not so transparent?

i looked in ui.core.js and ui.slider.js and could not find a way to adjust the property of the disable method...

anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slider [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/default.html) the disabled method adds the following css class to the slider div

```
.ui-state-disabled {
   background-image:none;
   opacity:0.35;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the stylesheet you are using. If you are using the UI stylesheet, then have a look in it. You can also find another stylesheet if you don't like the current stylesheet, or you can make your own.

Answer (score 0):

The transparency in its disabled state is in CSS, not JS.  Look for whatever's providing you with a style on the class `ui-slider-disabled`.